# cannot get nested child's data from firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am trying to get all the reviews for the post with a specific ID. I have tried all the solutions but it just never works. The same method works when I am trying to get "posts" (1 st level node) , but nested levels are not working

db:
[image]

```
 calculate_post_rating(post_id){

    console.log('this post id: '+post_id);

    let dbref = firebase.database().ref('/user-reviews/'+ post_id + '/');

    dbref.on('child_added', function (data){                

        console.log(data.key); //console is not even printing this, seems like this part is not even executed.

        console.log('rated by user: ' + data.val().rating);

 });
```

Comment: Are you sure that the post_id you are passing is correct and does exist?

Comment: At first glance the code looks correct. Have a look at the logging output of your app for any errors. If that doesn't help, see if you can reproduce the problem (with or without Ionic) in a tool like jsbin or stackblitz, so that we can have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier if you structure your data differently and avoid key inside key:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree

```
users-reviews: 
 - reviewingUserId 
   - comment: 'Wow'
   - rating: 5
   - subject: 'This may help you out'
```

Answer (score 0):

The code was actually working, the issue was that I was calling another function `"calculate_post_rating(post_id)"` from within the loop, like this:

that's were some of them skipped the calculated rating.

```
let dbref = firebase.database().ref('/posts/');

dbref.on('child_added', function (data){                

    console.log(data.key); //console is not even printing this, seems like this part is not even executed.

    console.log('rated by user: ' + data.val().rating);


let final_rating = calculate_rating(data.key); // this is where the expected final rating wasn't looping properly

});
```

from this may I conclude that: as the firebase functions are async , you should never call an external function from within the loop?